# Failed to install charlock_holmes on Windows 8 due to missing zlib

Tags: ruby, windows-8, rubygems, zlib

I'm trying to install charlock_holmes on Windows 8, but I can't point it to a valid zlib binary. I tried vaiours dll's from Cygwin and from zlib.net, with no luck. The question is, how to link to zlib properly?

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=D:\download\icu4c-4_0_1-Win64-msvc8\usr\local  --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt --with-zlib=WHATHEVER_WONT_WORK
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        d:/bin/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-icu-dir=D:\download\icu4c-4_0_1-Win64-msvc8\usr\local --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt --with-    zlib=WHATHEVER_WONT_WORK
checking for main() in -licuin... yes
checking for main() in -licuin... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
checking for main() in -lWHATHEVER_WONT_WORK... no
libz missing
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=d:/bin/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include
        --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --with-icu-lib
        --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --with-zlib


Gem files will remain installed in d:/bin/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to d:/bin/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Do you have Ruby Devkit installed - http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/ ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Other gems that require DevKit are installed without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libz.a goes to [devkit-dir]/mingw/lib, not [devkit-dir]/lib. Problem solved.